# Build options changed, rebuilding all exit status 1 [Error] Exit with code=1 MXChip Azure IoT Dev Kit

Tags: c++, azure, iot-devkit, mxchip, iot-workbench

I am just building my Device code of my Azure IoT Dev Kit MXChip and deploying to the device, but I am getting the error as below.

```
Build options changed, rebuilding all
GetStarted:9:21: error: utility.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
[Error] Exit with code=1
```

[image]

It was just working fine and I am not sure what exactly the problem is, anyone else has faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really a strange behavior, a simple workaround just fixed the issue. I just run clicked F1 again, type and select IoT Workbench: Device, then select Device Upload. And it was working fine again.

If it doesn't work for you,

1. Disconnect MXChip
2. Reopen the Workspace in VSCode
3. Do Azure Provisioning
4. Do device upload

Once it is done, you will get the message as below.

```
Programming Finished
Verify Started
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000002e msp: 0x200073fc
[Done] Uploaded the sketch: GetStarted.ino
```